# Wireframing from an image using matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D representation of an image as a surface using wireframes with matplotlib.

```
ig= mpimg.imread('testIMG.png');
X = np.linspace(0,len(ig[0]),len(ig[0])); #List of discrete x values
Y = np.linspace(0,len(ig[1]),len(ig[1])); #List of discrete y values

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Plot the wireframe
#I want to plot the image as f(x,y) and I can't understand why wireframe won't let me

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, ig[:,:,2], rstride=10, cstride=10)
plt.show()
```

The imread function gives me an MxNx3 array of M rows, N columns, and an RGB value for each point in the matrix. I don't understand how to use wireframe to plot that data properly. These z values aren't plotting what I expected (a checkerboard pattern), but instead a y=x line alternating between 0 and 1.

What do I need to do here? I want a series of cuboids in a 3D checkerboard pattern.
[Image of what I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJI83.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `np.meshgrid()`, so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d

ig = mpimg.imread('testIMG.png')
x = np.linspace(0, ig.shape[1], ig.shape[1]) #List of discrete x values
y = np.linspace(0, ig.shape[0], ig.shape[0]) #List of discrete y values

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

#Plot the wireframe
#I want to plot the image as f(x,y) and I can't understand why wireframe won't let me

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, ig[:,:,2], rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
```